# Will Predis be able to interact with a newer Redis version?

Tags: php, redis, predis

I'm working on writing a script to compare a couple caching methods my team will be using. I'm trying to set up a Predis client that will interact with the Redis already running there. The Redis that is running on the server is clocking in at version 4.0.9, while the latest predis notes list support for Redis profiles from 2.0 to 3.2. I was just wondering if the functionality of simple commands that have existed since 3.2 of Redis will function the same when using predis with our 4.0 config. If not, would I be able to just use exec to go through as if I was just using the command line interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember there were no API breaking changes for "simple" commands since 3.2. That said, it is possible that you won't be able to use the newer commands. Perhaps you should consider using Phpredis that is more up to date and maintained.

Comment: Also for some client libs that support a generic `command` interface, e.g. *hiredis*, you can always send new command to Redis server.